# Get all terms, including unchecked, or get the terms outside loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to return all the terms for a particular taxonomy (so eventually I can create a link for it).  At the moment, this function I've written only returns terms for the current post.  How can I just return a list of all of them?

```
<h2>Get terms</h2>
<?php
    $taxonomies=get_taxonomies('','object'); 
    foreach($taxonomies as $tax){
        echo "<h2>$tax->name</h2>";
        $terms = get_terms($tax->name);
        foreach($terms as $term){
            print_a($term->name);
        }
    }
?>
```

Just for a bit more detail, the site is about wine, and one taxonomy is grape type.  If the current wine is a Chardonnay, it returns "Chardonnay", but I'd like it to return "Chardonnay, Merlot, Pinot Grigio" etc.

The `print_a` function is just a `print_r` wrapped in pre tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, my fault I got it, the all important `hide_empty=0`

### Get terms

```
<?php
    $taxonomies=get_taxonomies('','object'); 
    foreach($taxonomies as $tax){
        echo "<h2>$tax->name</h2>";
        $terms = get_terms( $tax->name, 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
        foreach($terms as $term){
            print_a($term->name);
        }
    }
?>
```